# Issue while castor unmarshalling

Tags: castor

Getting below error while unmarshaling using castor

```
org.exolab.castor.xml.MarshalException: The class for the root element 'EnvelopeStatus' could not be found.{File: [not available]; line: 1; column: 55}
```

What can be done here?

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when you give wrong path to the xml tag which is mapped to a bean property. Try commenting all the mappings and remove the comments field by field to identify the mapping which is creating issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen if a clean restart of the application was not done properly. Try to restart application, that might resolve the issue.